# Showing a child filed in Django admin

Tags: python, django

```
#models.py

class shop(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(client , verbose_name=u'客戶')
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    shop_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class pickup(models.Model):
    order_parent = models.OneToOneField(order_parent)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(shop)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    pickup_date = models.DateField(editable=True)
    pickup_quoted_time = models.TimeField(editable=True)
    pickup_time_actual = models.TimeField(editable=True)
    special_instruction = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I wish to show the form of shop's address, telephone in the pickup admin interface. Is it possible doing in django?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, by using [inline model admins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

The django basic [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) talks about this. In your myapp/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Shop, Pickup

class ShopInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = shop

class PickupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [shopInline]

admin.site.register(Shop, ShopInline)
admin.site.register(Pickup, PickupAdmin)
```